# Click and touch events together in VUE 2.0 using vue-router

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, dom-events, vue-router

How to correctly use `click` and `touchstart` events together in *VUE2*?

Is the`vue-router` and its

```
<router-link to="/tap">tap</router-link>
```

ensure it by default?

If not, how to smartly add `touchstart` event to existing *VUE2* SPA application, who uses `vue-router` with `router-link` tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Touch events* trigger a *normal click*. This is the browser's default behaviour and is not closely related to the *Vue*.

So we can listen to *touches* by `@click` or by using `router-link` that actually also uses `@click`.